# Duvida sobre python/algoritmos básicos

Tags: python, algoritmo

Estou fazendo um desafio pessoal,desenvolver o menor programa possivel de gere uma sequencia de fibonati e que mostre a relacao de fi(numero de ouro).

Codigo mais recente :

```
nf = int(input("Quantos numeros da sequencia de fibonati voce quer ?"))
t = 0
tt = 1
ttt = 1
tf = 0


def fibo(a, b, c, d):
    d = a
    c = b + a
    print("{} - ".format(a),end='')
    a = b
    b = c
    return a, b, c, d


for i in range(nf):
    t,tt,ttt,tf = fibo(t, tt, ttt, tf)
print(tf,".")
print(tt / t)
```

O problema aparece quando tento finilizar,a queria que a sequencia termisse com um ".".Como percebesse no codigo eu tentei usar um quarto arguemnto na funcao,mas ele recebe o ultimo valor de t,entao acaba que nao adianta de muita coisa.

Não sei como que posso fazer,e essa é a minha duvida,e caso alguem posso me dar conselos de como eu posso diminuir ainda mais o codigo eu ficaria bastante agradecido >.</

Comment: https://ideone.com/5Hfamy

Answer (score -1):

consegui fazer o que eu quero,mas aqui tem 20 linhas,caso de pra diminuir me fala ai =)

```
nf = int(input("Quantos numeros da sequencia de fibonati voce quer ?"))
t = 0
tt = 1
ttt = 1
print("{} - ".format(t),end="")


def fibo(a, b, c):
    c = b + a
    print("{} - ".format(b),end='')
    a = b
    b = c
    return a, b, c,


for i in range(nf - 2):
    t,tt,ttt = fibo(t, tt, ttt)
print(ttt,".")
print(tt / t)
```

Comment: Se está preocupado só com a quantidade de linhas, não crie uma função: https://ideone.com/tgqUdq - se quer menos linhas ainda: https://ideone.com/BOT19x (embora eu não recomende isso, pois o código fica mais confuso e difícil de ler - afinal, menos linhas não é necessariamente melhor)

Comment: eu fiz isso,ficou com 9 linhas que me lembre

Comment: 'nao sei por tava ensistindo em fazer uma funcao pra fiboKEWKEKKE